# Number of edges vs number of vertices in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, euclidean-geometry, polygons

I was thinking about the name "Triangle", when I realized that although we usually think of polygons in terms of the number of their sides. However, when I searched the origin of the word "polygon", Oxford Languages states the following: "late 16th century: via late Latin from Greek polugōnon, neuter (used as a noun) of polugōnos ‘many-angled’."

Therefore, I was wondering whether polygons would always have the same number of edges and vertices. In formulating a proof, I considered a simply connected graph in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and using Euler's characteristic formula $V+F-E=2$, I concluded that this statement should always hold since there is 1 face formed on the inside of the simply connected graph and 1 on the outside, resulting in 2 faces in total and giving the desired identity.

Please correct me if this is not rigorous, as I have not studied graph theory formally and am only basing this on my limited knowledge of it.

Finally, I'd like to ask whether there are other known useful relationships between vertices in faces in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Also, is there an angle for each vertex in $\mathbb{R}^2$? What about in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (is there an angle for each vertex)?

Comment: What about *what* in $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Is there an angle for every vertex in $\mathbb{R}^n$? Sorry if the wording was unclear.

Comment: Defining a "polygon" in graph theory as a closed cycle that never revisits a vertex, you don't need Euler's formula, nor even a planar graph to see that it must have the same number of edges and vertices. Following the cycle imparts a direction to each edge - the direction of travel. Cut the cycle up at the vertices. Assign to each edge, its down-stream vertex. This alots every edge with a single vertex, and every vertex is allotted to a single edge. Thus the numbers of each must be the same.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you for the insight, that's an elegant proof.